# Why WebSocket interceptor doesn't invoked?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I am creating an interceptor as described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket/stomp/authentication-token-based.html for authentication

```
  @Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketConfig extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                        MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                }
                return message;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
        .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
        .withSockJS();

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

But the flow never comes into "preSend" method, the client (FireFox browser) said 403 Forbidden. How to call preSend? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have removed .withSockJS();
And everything does work.